# Grails security filter and /index.gsp

Tags: grails

I have an application where the login page is using Facebook Graph API and the login button is at http://localhost:8080/ or index.gsp. So, I created a filter that check every action on every controller controller:'*', action:'*'

So, when I go to http://localhost:8080/ it's blocked as well. How can I apple the filter to every action and every controller except the homepage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter matching all controllers except the `HomeController`:

```
allButHome(controller:'home', invert:true) {
}
```